# gradle.properties will be overridden by Jenkins environment variables on a build?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

my question is how setting variables using **gradle.properties** in an Android project, when I run a job in **Jenkins** **CI**, and I set the variables to override the ones in **gradle.properties**.

1. Will this varialbes be overriden by Jenkins?
2. Can I override **gradle.properties** in *Jenkinsfile* pipeline?
3. Will be good to inject a new **gradle.properties** on building time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pretty much depends how are your variables defined. Here's an example

```
ext.greeting = project.properties['greeting'] ?: 'hello'

task greet << {
    println greeting
}
```

`greeting` would be overwritten with command line like `gradle -Pgreeting=welcome greet`.

Comment: Thats exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you!